# #MaxHotkeysPerInterval error in AHK. If statement wrong?

Tags: autohotkey

I want my Vol. Up/Down to have multiple 'profiles' depending on a variable called 'startVar'.
But the code I wrote does not work.

```
Volume_Down::
    if(startVar == 0 ){
        SendInput {Volume_Up}
        ;SoundSet -5
        return
    }
    else if (startVar == 1 ){
        Send {Left}
    return
    }
return

Volume_Up::
    if(startVar == 0 ){
        SendInput {Volume_Down}
        ;SoundSet +5
        ;Sleep 30
        return
    }
    else if (startVar == 1 ){
        Send {Right}
    return
    }
return
```

I want the Vol.-Up/Down keys to either act like Left/Right or like usual.
But when I want them act like Vol.-Up/Down I get that error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2oAI.png)
I commented the function SoundSet although that worked because I want to have the Windows-Volume-GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving this message because the **[keyboard hook](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InstallKeybdHook.htm)** isn't used in your script to implement those hotkeys, which causes the Send command to trigger them over 70 times in a 2 second interval (default values for **[#MaxHotkeysPerInterval](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_MaxHotkeysPerInterval.htm)** and **[#HotkeyInterval](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_HotkeyInterval.htm)** if you don't specify them in your script).

To avoid this problem, specify **[#UseHook](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_UseHook.htm)** somewhere above the definition of the hotkeys or prefix them with the [dollar symbol **$**](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar).